# DynamoDB data format to plan JSON using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I'm having an S3 bucket with contains data copied form DynamoDB using DataPipline. So data in s3 is in the below format (in s3 it will be single line).

```
    {
      "file": {
        "S": "file1.mp4"
      },
      "id": {
        "S": "1"
      },
      "canvas": {
        "S": "This is Canvas1"
      }
    }
```

I want to convert it into different format required by another application (which I don't have control on).

Expected output format:

```
    {
      "file": "file1.mp4",
      "id": "1",
      "canvas": "This is Canvas1"
    }
```

Is there a way to do this in spark? I can't use Lambda as number of files will be huge.

Note: JSON in S3 will be in single line. I formatted it here for better view and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) that in turn used will use spark to reformat.

You can see the `Json flattening` example with glue Relationalize Transform [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/).

Briefly, with Glue , you will need to do

1. After Creating a Crawler in AWS Glue, let it create a schema in a catalog (database).
2. Create a Glue job for transforming the json, here select json as your output file again. This will use the transform step to flatten the data using Rationalize class